# FFMPEG with GPU-Accel: map AVFrame directly to OpenGL-Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG with GPU acceleration to decode and display a video. All examples (i.e. [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/hw__decode_8c_source.html)) for this topic explain how to set-up hw-accel and how to decode a video frame. Afterwards the frame (AVFrame) is getting copied to CPU memory for further processing.
However, I would like to access the GPU memory of the AVFrame directly, in order to map it to a OpenGL texture for rendering.

```
// setup ffmpeg hw stuff
...
AVCodecContext *ctx;
AVFrame *frame;
...
// at one point I do
avcodec_receive_frame(ctx, frame);

// the frame data resides on GPU and I would need to use av_hwframe_transfer_data() 
// in order to access the frame data on CPU.
// However, how can I access the frame data to map it to a OpenGL texture for rendering,
// while leaving the data on the GPU?
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous - there are numerous HW-accelerated decoders available in FFmpeg, which require completely different approaches to be displayed in OpenGL / Direct3D / other context depending on platform and used HW-accelerated API.

Comment: @gkv311 Assuming I use a CUDA based H265 decoder, how would I proceed to map the decoded frame (which resides on the GPU) to a OpenGL texture? Or can you point me to any other example in order to get an idea about the pipeline?